# Chinese Dialogue Assignment

Tags: simplified-characters, reading, conversation

For this assignment, we were tasked to create a dialogue with the following criteria:

```
1.Talking about oneself, family and time.
In this dialogue students will exchange basic information about oneself
and family members. Be sure to include dates and times.)

(1) 姓⋯⋯贵姓         叫          名字                  
(2) Questions ending with 呢 and 吗
(3) 是
(4) 不
(5) 也
(6) 个
(7) The usage of “二” and “两”
(8) Question words 谁、什么、几个?
(9) 有 and 没有
(10) 都， 不都，都不
(11) Talking about date and time:
今天是几月几号，星期几？
你的生日是几月几号？
你今年多大？
现在几点(钟)？
星期四晚上八点(钟)见。(Time + 见) 
(12) 请 + Person + VO
(13) …, 还是 (Alternative questions)
(14) A-not-A questions
(15) 还有
(16) 可是
(17) 为什么 ， 因为
```

I was just wondering if someone can proofread the following dialogue.
There are three characters A, B, and C. As for the dashes we plan on filling those later.

START OF THE DIALOGUE

**A**: 你好
**B**: 你好

**A**: 我叫 钱贝儿，你叫什么名字
**B**: 我叫那厮其。钱先生，你是中国学生吗？

**A**: 不是，我是美国学生，你呢？
**B**: 我也是美国学生

**A**: 你家有几口人？
**B**: 我家有五口人，我爸爸，妈妈，一个姐姐，一个弟弟，和我。钱先生，你家有几口人吗？

**A**: 我家有四口人，爸爸，妈妈，弟弟，和我. 这是我的照片。
**B**: 这是谁。

**A**: 这是我爸爸
**B**: 你爸爸做什么工作?

**A**: 我爸爸是经理, 你爸爸呢？
**B**: 我爸爸是医生.

**A**: 我妈妈也是医生。你姐姐和弟弟都是大学生吗？
**B**: 他们不都是大学生。你弟弟呢？

**A**: 他是中学生。
**B**: 钱贝尔，现在几点？

**A**: 两点中，为什么?
**B**: 因为，我的朋友来了。

=====Third Person Comes in=====

**C**：你好，那厮其。
**A**：他是谁？
**B**：你好，他是我的朋友。

**A**：Oh，请问，你贵姓？
**C**：我姓－－，我叫－－。

**A**：你是中国大学生吗？
**C**：不是，我是美国大学生。

**A**：－－先生，你家有几口人吗？
**C**：我家有六口人，我爸爸，妈妈，一个弟弟，两个妹妹和我。

**C**：那厮，今天是几月几号，星期几？
**B**：今天是－－月－－号，星期－－。

**C**：明天，我弟弟的生日。
**A**：太好了，－－先生，你弟弟今年几岁?
**C**:---

**B**: 钱先生,你明天忙不忙?
**A**: 早上，明天我很忙可是晚上不忙。

**C**：很好，晚上我请你们吃晚饭因为我弟弟的生日。
**A**：谢谢
**B**：谢谢

**C**：你们喜欢中国菜还是美国菜？
**A**：我喜欢美国人，可是喜欢中国菜。
**B**：我还喜欢中国菜。

**C**：明天晚上，七点三刻，怎么样？
**B**：不好，八点半，怎么样？
**A**：很好。

**C**：好，明天晚上见。
**A**：再见！
**B**：再见！

END OF THE DIALOGUE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**X: wrong, V:suggest**

START OF THE DIALOGUE

A: 你好 B: 你好

A: 我叫 钱贝儿，你叫什么名字 B: 我叫那厮其。钱先生，你是中国学生吗？

A: 不是，我是美国学生，你呢？ B: 我也是美国学生

A: 你家有几口人？ B: 我家有五口人，**我爸爸，妈妈，一个姐姐，一个弟弟，和我。钱先生，你家有几口人呢(X吗)？**

A: 我家有四口人，爸爸，妈妈，弟弟，和我. 这是我的照片。 B: 这是谁。

A: 这是我爸爸 B: 你爸爸做什么工作?

A: 我爸爸是经理, 你爸爸呢？ B: 我爸爸是医生.

A: 我妈妈也是医生。你姐姐和弟弟都是大学生吗？ B: **(V他们)不都是大学生**。你弟弟呢？

A: 他是中学生。 B: 钱贝尔，现在几点？

A: **两点钟(X中)**，**怎么了(X为什么)**? B: **(V因为)**，**我的朋友要来(X来了)**。

=====Third Person Comes in=====

C：你好，那厮其。 A：他是谁？ B：你好，他是我的朋友。

A：Oh，请问，你贵姓？ C：我姓－－，我叫－－。

A：你是中国大学生吗？ C：不是，我是美国大学生。

A：－－先生，你家有几口人呢(X吗)？ C：我家有六口人，我爸爸，妈妈，一个弟弟，两个妹妹和我。

C：那厮，今天是几月几号，星期几？ B：今天是－－月－－号，星期－－。

C：**(V)明天是我弟弟的生日。** A：太好了，－－先生，你弟弟今年几岁? C:---

B: 钱先生,你明天忙不忙? A: **我明天早上很忙, 可是晚上不忙。**

C：很好，晚上我请你们吃晚饭, **(V)我弟弟的生日。** A：谢谢 B：谢谢

C：你们喜欢中国菜还是美国菜？ A：**(V)虽然我喜欢美国人**，可是喜欢中国菜。 B：**我也(X还)喜欢中国菜。**

C：明天晚上，七点三刻，怎么样？ B：**(V不好，)**八点半，怎么样？ A：很好。

C：好，明天晚上见。 A：再见！ B：再见！

END OF THE DIALOGUE